# Change href BEFORE anchor will activate url

Tags: google-apps-script, anchor, href

I want to generate a url including some parameters based on input of the user.
I do have an anchor and by using addMouseDownHandler or addClickHandler I can change the link of the anchor .
Problem is this changed link will be activated ONLY after I click on the anchor a second time and the (at creation time) specified url will be activated the first time I click the anchor.

```
function onMouseDownAnchor(e)
{
 Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));// you can see the source parameter in e that returns the widgets ID of the button you clicked to call the handler

   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   var btnAnchor = app.getElementById('btnAnchor');
   var newLink = 'http://www.google.com';
   btnAnchor.setHref(newLink)
  Logger.log('onMouseDownAnchor');

   return app;
}
```

How can I change href of an anchor BEFORE the anchor activates the url it has at the time I click on it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself .
Instead of using

```
onMouseDownAnchor
```

I only need to use

```
onMouseOverAnchor
```

so the working code becomes

```
function onMouseOverAnchor(e)
{
 Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));// you can see the source parameter in e that returns the widgets ID of the button you clicked to call the handler

   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   var btnAnchor = app.getElementById('btnAnchor');
   var newLink = 'http://www.google.com';
   btnAnchor.setHref(newLink)
  Logger.log('onMouseOverAnchor');

   return app;
}
```

and, of course,

```
 var anchor = myApp.createAnchor("", siteUrl)
                  .setId('btnAnchor').setName('bntAnchor')
                  .setHeight(heightButton).setWidth(widthButton)            
                  .setStyleAttribute('backgroundImage', 'url(' + picButton + ')');

  var onMouseOverAnchor = myApp.createServerHandler('onMouseOverAnchor');
  anchor.addMouseOverHandler(onMouseOverAnchor);   // This will change the href of the anchor
```

must have been created in the doGet-function